# Firebase custom notification sound not playing

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-push-notification

I'm working with Firebase Cloud Messaging, sending notifications from mongoDB to react-native application using react-native-push-notification.

Notification is working, but I can't play the custom notification I added in my android app in /res/raw folder.

[image: my_sound]

My code:

```js
const message = {
    "to": userFinded.deviceToken,
    "notification": {
      "title": 'Body test',
      "color": '#ff9d00',
      "sound": 'my_sound', //Not working
    },
  };
```

[FCM Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

I also tried to follow the [documentation of react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and did this:

```js
PushNotification.localNotification({
    /* Android Only Properties */
    channelId: 'fcm_fallback_notification_channel', // (required) channelId, if the channel doesn't exist, notification will not trigger.

    soundName: 'my_sound.mp3', // (optional) Sound to play when the notification is shown. Value of 'default' plays the default sound. It can be set to a custom sound such as 'android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound'. It will look for the 'my_sound' audio file in 'res/raw' directory and play it. default: 'default' (default sound is played)
  });

  PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: 'fcm_fallback_notification_channel', // (required)
      channelName: 'My channel', // (required)
      soundName: 'my_sound.mp3', // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
    });
```

I tried different versions:

```js
soundName: 'my_sound.mp3';
soundName: 'my_sound';
soundName: 'android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound';
soundName: 'android.resource://com.seeed/raw/my_sound';
```

Sometimes the notification sound is the default one, sometimes I don't have any sound.

Any help please?

Comment: did you try
soundName: 'android.resource://com.seeed/raw/my_sound.mp3' ??

Answer (score 0):

you need to send android_channel_id also

like this

```
const message = {
"to": userFinded.deviceToken,
"notification": {
  "title": 'Body test',
  "color": '#ff9d00',
  "sound": 'my_sound.mp3', 
  "android_channel_id": "fcm_fallback_notification_channel" 
},
```